# Поворот змейки

Tags: алгоритм

Доброго времени суток! подскажите алгоритм поворота змейки. То-есть, чтобы тело змейки изгибалось несколько раз. как-то так:

```
*******************
*
*******************
                  *
            *******
```

Comment: Что все помешались на этих змейках?! Вы не виртуал случайно? ;)

Answer (score 4):

Если я правильно понял Вашу проблему, то вероятно такое решение Вам поможет:

Если тело змейки на данном этапе состоит из, допустим, 10 сегментов, то достаточно будет хранить 10 координат ее тела. Координаты упорядочены, тоесть в начале хранимого массива содержится координата хвоста, а в конце массива - координата головы змейки. При следующем шаге необходимо просто стереть последнюю координату (сегмент из хвоста змейки) и добавить в конец новую координату, где будет храниться "новая" голова змейки. Дальше заново прорисовываем змейку.

Comment: вопрос не про то, как вообще поворачивать змейку, а как двигать массив, одновременно поворачивая его в две-три стороны.

Comment: Вся мысль изложена верно, но на момент роста змейки, нужно притормозить удаление хвоста на столько тактов, на сколько змейка должна вырости.

Answer (score 1):

Когда я писал змейку, я завел массив самой змеи: в нем хранил координаты тела змеи:

```
( (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4) )
```

После очередного движения, я наносил на общую карту эту змею. А при движении змеи необходимо чтобы одна из координат повторялась, а другая отличалась на 1.

**Добавлено**

Еще можно хранить очередь действий. Т.е. когда человек нажимает кнопку, действие записывается в массив, но выполняется только при очередном такте. Если достигнут конец очереди, то переписывается последняя запись. Например (очередь из 2 действий):

1. Человек по очредено нажимает на кнопки ↑ → ←
2. В массив записывается (↑, →), и т.к. достигнут конец очереди, то последняя запись перезаписывается: (↑, ←)
3. Начинается новый такт, проверяется очередь действий (там наверх), изменяем очередь: (←)
4. Человек нажимает кнопку ↑ - записывается в очередь: (←, ↑)

Comment: Проблема в том, что сейчас у меня при нажатии на кнопку змея поворачивает вся сразу, а я хочу так: нажал кнопку вверх, змея начала поворачивать вверх, нажал влево - змея поворачивает влево, продолжая поворачивать вверх. Надеюсь мне удалось внятно выразить проблему.

Comment: добавил ответ. Надеюсь правильно понял вашу проблему )

Comment: очередь это хорошо - но мне непонятно, как в этом случае двигать массив.

Comment: при очередном тике, когда необходимо подвинуть змею, берешь первое значение из массива задач (т.е. куда надо повернуть), и меняешь направление (при этом удаляешь это направление из массива задач). А соответственно твоему направлению змеи меняешь координаты. 

Для данного хранения змей, который я привел, узнаешь новую ячейку головы, сдвигаешь координаты в хвост а на голову ставишь новые значения.

Comment: > очередь это хорошо - но мне непонятно, как в этом случае двигать массив.

В ответе @pelmeshka80 как раз и говорится, как сдвигать массив: удалять хвост и прибавлять голову в направлении движения.